# OnTextChanged event doesn't fire on CKEditor control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, event-handling, ckeditor

I have a checkbox, a button, and a CKEditor control (v3.6.1) that I've added to an existing asp.net webform page.  Clicking the button saves the status of the checkbox and the contents of the CKEditor to the database and displays a saved successfully message.  If the user modifies either one, the message should disappear.  Well, the OnTextChanged event isn't firing on the CKEditor so that the label displaying the message can be hidden.  I have tried doing this with javascript using the onkeypress event.  I wrapped the CKEditor in a  tag and put the onkeypress="..." on that with no luck.  I even used jQuery to attach a function to the OnTextChanged (tried OnChanged too) event on document ready with no luck.  This is driving me crazy as to why this simple thing won't work and it's the only thing holding me up from completing my project (at least going to the next phase).  Can someone please help me with this as to why this isn't working.  Code pertinent to this issue is pasted below:

.aspx

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <CKEditor:CKEditorControl runat="server" ID="txtClientProtocols" name="txtClientProtocols" Width="1000" Height="370" EnterMode="P"
         ResizeEnabled="false" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtClientProtocols_TextChanged"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
   </td>
</tr>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void txtClientProtocols_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lblSuccess.Style["visibility"] = "hidden";
}
```

I did some research but haven't found anything that stood out as a solution.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Following the recent CKEditor 3.6.2 release we would like to announce
>   the availability of our integrated version for ASP.NET. The ASP.NET
>   control was updated to the latest CKEditor version and contains all
>   the bug fixes and new features introduced in CKEditor 3.6.2, including
>   initial support for iOS5 and some API additions.
>
> Apart from the changes included in the editor, some new features are
>   offered exclusively for the ASP.NET control: the OnTextChanged event
>   is now fired and the AutoPostBack property is available.
>
> The scripts registration has been moved from OnLoad to OnPreRender, so
>   setting configuration in the code should now be always working. Issues
>   with Ajax postback should be also gone.

[What's new ASP.NET](http://ckeditor.com/whatsnew-asp.net)

You should upgrade your version.